# RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build

Tags: macos, jupyter-lab

I'm working to troubleshoot the installation of an extension in Jupyter lab (https://github.com/krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp). I'm using MacOS 11.4. Following extension installation, a rebuild is required. I used

```
jupyter lab build
```

and

```
jupyter lab build --minimize=FALSE
```

(to potentially address any memory issues), however the rebuild fails with the following message:

```
An error occured.
RuntimeError: JupyterLab failed to build
See the log file for details:  /var/folders/hm/dsc1zn0j30s31yp_n6911dym0000gn/T/jupyterlab-debug-v9tx8kpz.log
```

Based on similar issues, I believe there is a memory issue that needs to be addressed. That said, I cannot identify the location of the log file to troubleshoot further. The file does not show up in a spotlight search, nor do any of the directories listed.

Answer (score 6):

As the author of this extension I do not recommend installing it from source (or installing any other JupyterLab extension which is also distributed as a prebuilt extension from source, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67391886/6646912) for details). Instead please use JupyterLab 3.0+ and install the prebuilt version using `pip` or `conda` (which does not require the build step) as demonstrated in the README.

Please uninstall the source extension:

```
jupyter labextension uninstall @krassowski/jupyterlab-lsp
```

Ensure it is gone by checking:

```
jupyter labextension list
```

Update JupyterLab:

```
pip install -U jupyterlab>=3
# or if using conda:
# conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab>=3
```

And then install the extension:

```
pip install jupyterlab-lsp
# or if using conda:
# conda install -c conda-forge jupyterlab-lsp
```

And follow with installation of language servers as needed and explained in the README. In case of any problems please let me know.

Comment: Kind thanks for the detailed response here.